# Possible to revoke/hide Redshift schema with identity_type public from a group?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a few schemas I'd like to hide from a group of users in redshift. The schemas are public (created that way with Stitch), so revoke does not work on these. Is there a way to hide or revoke these from the group that I'm missing?